# Python: Regular Expression pattern can occur multiple times but is NOT conditional

Tags: python, regex

**Hi everyone!** I am having trouble formatting a regex in `Python`. What I would like the regex to find is `_D`, but after this a `D` or `2` can follow. But this pattern of `(D|2)` can occur multiple times (or, not at all). The regex which I am using now is:

`re.search('_D(D|2)*', variable)`

I have tried:

`re.search('_D(D|2)(D|2)*', variable)`

But this didn't work for me either. Could someone help me out to make the pattern optional but multiple times?

Comment: `*` already means "0 or more times" and therefore implies optionality. Did you mean to write `_D(D|2)*` instead of `_D*(D|2)`?

Comment: YES! Sorry! _D*(D|2) works for me! Would you like to post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @AnnaJeanine, `_D*(D|2)` should not work for you, which means arbitary number of `D` prefixed by a `_` and suffixed by a `D|2`, but your requirement in the question were different.

Comment: Could ypu please explain what string you have in `variable`, and what is *static* (always present) and what is *dynamic* (which part is optional).

Comment: You could replace *(D|2)* by *[D2]*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` suffix means "0 or more times" and therefore already implies optionality. You want to put it after `(D|2)` for that group to be repeatable:

```
re.search('_D(D|2)*', variable)
```